# How one can draw a similar squared Venn diagram figure?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I'm wondering how could I draw a `Venn` diagram like this one?

Some dummy data:

```
A <- sample(1:1000, 400, replace = FALSE); 
B <- sample(1:1000, 600, replace = FALSE);
C <- sample(1:1000, 350, replace = FALSE);
D <- sample(1:1000, 550, replace = FALSE);
E <- sample(1:1000, 375, replace = FALSE);



 venn.diagram(x = list(A = A,D = D,B = B,C = C), filename = "Venn.tiff",
col = "transparent", fill = c("cornflowerblue","green","yellow","darkorchid1"),
alpha = 0.50, label.col = c("orange", "white", "darkorchid4", "white", "white", 
"white",    "white", "white", "darkblue", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"darkgreen", "white"), cex = 1.5, fontfamily = "serif", fontface = "bold",
cat.col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "darkorchid4"), cat.cex = 1.5,
cat.pos = 0, cat.dist = 0.07, cat.fontfamily = "serif", rotation.degree = 270,
margin = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know any venn function able to do such format. You can use your own code and save it as `.svg` or `.pdf` and edit it using incscape or similar vector graphics editors.